# Erro com requisições com scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scrapy, web-scraping

Tenho um arquivo em csv com alguns urls que precisam ser acessadas.

```
http://www.icarros.com.br/Audi, Audi
http://www.icarros.com.br/Fiat, Fiat
http://www.icarros.com.br/Chevrolet, Chevrolet
```

Tenho um spider para fazer todas as requições.

```
import scrapy
import csv
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class ModelSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "config_brands"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.icarros.com/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        file = open("files/brands.csv")
        reader = csv.reader(file)

        for line in reader:
            yield scrapy.Request(line[0], self.success_connect, self.error_connect)

    def success_connect(self, response):
        self.log('Entrei na url: %s' %response.url)

    def error_connect(self, response):
        self.log('Nao foi possivel %s' %response.url)
```

Quando tento rodar o spider ele não consegue conectar em nenhuma das urls sendo que se eu entrar com a mesma url no navegador ele consegue acessar normalmente. E minha função de errback também não funciona.

Debug:

```
2016-09-09 10:17:00 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.icarros.com.br/principal/index.jsp> (referer: None)
2016-09-09 10:17:00 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <<BOUND METHOD MODELSPIDER.ERROR_CONNECT OF <MODELSPIDER 'CONFIG_BRANDS' AT 0X7F7D18B45990>> http://www.icarros.com.br/Audi> (failed 1 times): 400 Bad Request
2016-09-09 10:17:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <<BOUND METHOD MODELSPIDER.ERROR_CONNECT OF <MODELSPIDER 'CONFIG_BRANDS' AT 0X7F7D18B45990>> http://www.icarros.com.br/Audi> (failed 2 times): 400 Bad Request
2016-09-09 10:17:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <<BOUND METHOD MODELSPIDER.ERROR_CONNECT OF <MODELSPIDER 'CONFIG_BRANDS' AT 0X7F7D18B45990>> http://www.icarros.com.br/Audi> (failed 3 times): 400 Bad Request
2016-09-09 10:17:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <<BOUND METHOD MODELSPIDER.ERROR_CONNECT OF <MODELSPIDER 'CONFIG_BRANDS' AT 0X7F7D18B45990>> http://www.icarros.com.br/Audi> (referer: http://www.icarros.com.br/principal/index.jsp)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem ao menos duas formas de resolver isso.

1. A primeira é especificar ao *middleware* que você deseja lidar com códigos de resposta que estejam fora do intervalo *200-300*, faça isso no `handle_httpstatus_list`:

   ```
   class ModelSpider(scrapy.Spider):
       name = "config_brands"
       handle_httpstatus_list = [400, 403]
   ```

   Veja a [**documentação**](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror) para mais detalhes.

   > E minha função de `errback` também não funciona.

   Especifique o `callback` e `errback`:

   ```
   yield scrapy.Request(line[0], callback = self.success_connect, 
                                  errback = self.error_connect)
   ```

   Ao fazer essas duas alterações o teu código deve funcionar como o esperado.

---

2. Uma alternativa é usar o método [`start_requests`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests), que deve ser mais apropriado que o [`parse`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.parse) neste caso pois você quer acessar uma lista de URLs, o `parse` geralmente é usado para processar a resposta.

   Você pode fazer assim:

   ```
   class ModelSpider(scrapy.Spider):
       name = "config_brands"

       def start_requests(self):
           with open('brands.csv', 'r') as f:
               reader = csv.reader(f)

               for url, modelo in reader:
                   yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.success_connect, 
                                              errback = self.error_connect)
   ```

   No `sucess_connect` você trata a resposta recebida, veja um exemplo:

   ```
   def success_connect(self, response):
       self.logger.info('Entrei na url: {}'.format(response.url))

       anuncios = response.xpath('//div[@class="dados_veiculo"]')

       for anuncio in anuncios:
           titulo = anuncio.xpath('a[@class="clearfix"]/@title').extract()[0]
           valor = anuncio.xpath('a/p/text()').extract()[0]

           # Para lidar com caracteres acentuados
           titulo = titulo.encode('utf-8')
           valor = valor.encode('utf-8')

           print ("{}: {}".format(titulo, valor))
   ```

   No `error_connect` faça o tratamento, ou informe o erro:

   ```
   def error_connect(self, failure):
           self.logger.error('Nao foi possivel: {}'.format(failure.url))
   ```

Se preferir tratar adequadamente exceções que ocorram no processamento da requisição, dê uma olhada nesse [**exemplo na documentação**](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing).